# SVN "Share project was failed"

Tags: eclipse, svn, fdt

I get this error :

> Share project was failed.
>
> svn: Error writing entries file for
>   'C:\workspace2\Test'
>
> svn: Entry '' has inconsistent
>   repository root and url

But we get this error only on a particular PC. Also if we move the workspace in a network drive, everything works fine.
We are using FDT(eclipse based IDE).

We are totaly new to SVN...

I am looking for any advice who will helping us solving the problem

**UPDATE:**

Without any particular change the problem is gone ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you reproduced the issue with the latest Eclipse (Galileo 3.5.1)?
And what  Subversion Eclipse plugin are you using? ([Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) or [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/)?)

There was a [bug with Subversive](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=269665) with path including a special character (like `~`).
In your case, check the '`C:\workspace2\Test`' has no special character in it, like a space at the very end. ('`C:\workspace2\Test`')

Comment: We are using Subversive.
There is no special character in the path.
Thanks for the reply !